# Is this true for $n\geq 0$: $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty} e^{-x^2}\frac d {dx}\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}}e^{x^2}=1 $?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $T_n$ denote  Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind, I w'd like to show the below  limit if it is true which it's [hold](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim+e%5E%7B-x%C2%B2%7D+(%5Cfrac%7B4x%5E3-3x%7D%7B8x%5E4-8x%C2%B2%2B1%7De%5E(x%C2%B2)))%27,+x+to+infty) for few first of them then how do i show this if it is true

> for $n\geq0$ :$$\lim_{x\to \infty} e^{-x^2}\frac{d}{dx}\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}} e^{x^2} = 1 \text{ ?}$$

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** 
$$\exp(-x^2)\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(f(x)\cdot\exp(x^2))=2x\cdot f(x)+f'(x)$$

**Extra Hint:**
$$\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}}\sim\frac{1}{2x}$$

$$\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{2xT_n-T_{n+1}}{2xT_{n+1}}=\frac{1}{2x}-\frac{T_{n-1}}{2xT_{n+1}}$$

Comment: Thanks , but how do i can assure that the limit is 1, i meant the behavior of f(x) according to  n geq 0 ?

Comment: Have you looked at what the above expression ends up as for $f=\frac{T_n}{T_{n+1}}$?